# Stoping an activity from an interface

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an onClickListener for a button which make some things and then I would like to stop the activity but it's impossible to get the activity Intent since I'm on a interface.

Thats how it looks like:

```
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            //blah blah blah
            this.stopService(this.getIntent()); // <-- impossiblee, compliation error.
        }
    });
```

Comment: `this.stopService(getIntent());` or `this.stopService(YourActivityName.this.getIntent());`

Comment: The method stopService is not a part of the OnClickListener interface.

Comment: sorry , try this instead : 
`stopService(getIntent());` or `YourActivityName.this.stopService(YourActivityName.this.getIntent());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stopping Activity you will need to use `finish()` method of Activity

```
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        //blah blah blah
        Current_Activity.this.finish();
    }
  });
```

and `stopService` service method used for stopping service instead of Activity

**EDIT :** if you want to stop an service then use

```
 Current_Activity.this.stopService(Current_Activity.this.getIntent());
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
MyActivity.this.getIntent()
```

Comment: Can you post the modified code? Also post where this is code is in, is it onCreate of an Activity ?

Comment: I deleted my comment since I did a mistake, your answer is correct. If I could mark 2 answers as correct I would. Thanks.